# Obtain Date Values from Database then Set as String

Tags: java, mysql, string, date, javafx

How to obtain Date values from database then set it as a string. Can anyone tell me why the below code is not working properly? This is the portion giving trouble:

```
// Date d = rs.getDate("PatientBirthDate");

// DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
// String date = df.format(d);

while (rs.next()) {
    pid.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("PatientID")));
    ssn.setText(rs.getString("PatientSSN"));
    firstname.setText(rs.getString("PatientFname"));
    lastname.setText(rs.getString("PatientLname"));
    gender.setText(rs.getString("PatientGender"));
    // dob.setText(date);
    streetnum.setText(rs.getString("PatientStreetNo"));
    streetname.setText(rs.getString("PatientStreetName"));
    city.setText(rs.getString("PatientCity"));
    state.setText(rs.getString("PatientState"));
    zip.setText(rs.getString("PatientZip"));
    homephone.setText(rs.getString("PatientHomePhone"));
    cellphone.setText(rs.getString("PatientCellPhone"));
    email.setText(rs.getString("PatientEmailAddress"));
    inspolicy.setText(rs.getString("InsurancePolicyNumber"));
    inscompany.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("InsuranceCompID")));
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception, compilation error etc.  What is the problem?

Comment: What's *"not working properly"*?  Is the `date` a valid date/time column or is a text column?  Can you get a `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp` value from the database?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I hope that you are calling `rs.getDate("PatientBirthDate");` within the `while (rs.next)` loop...

Comment: Need code sounds really bad!

Answer (score 0):

Why you are reading the date outside the loop?

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");    
while (rs.next()) {
        pid.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("PatientID")));
        ssn.setText(rs.getString("PatientSSN"));
        firstname.setText(rs.getString("PatientFname"));
        lastname.setText(rs.getString("PatientLname"));
        gender.setText(rs.getString("PatientGender"));
        Date d = rs.getDate("PatientBirthDate");
        String date = df.format(d);
        dob.setText(date);
        streetnum.setText(rs.getString("PatientStreetNo"));
        streetname.setText(rs.getString("PatientStreetName"));
        city.setText(rs.getString("PatientCity"));
        state.setText(rs.getString("PatientState"));
        zip.setText(rs.getString("PatientZip"));
        homephone.setText(rs.getString("PatientHomePhone"));
        cellphone.setText(rs.getString("PatientCellPhone"));
        email.setText(rs.getString("PatientEmailAddress"));
        inspolicy.setText(rs.getString("InsurancePolicyNumber"));
        inscompany.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("InsuranceCompID")));
    }
```